# how to define the input and output for the interface in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Here I have a simple example below.

```
module A(o,clk,rst,i);
  output o;
  input i,clk,rst;
  ...
endmodule
```

and here is an interface class definition below.

```
interface my_if(input bit clk);
  logic o,rst,i;
  wire clk;

  clocking cb@(posedge clk);
    input o;         // why input here ?
    output i,rst;    // why output here ?
  endclocking
  ...
endinterface
```

My question is how to decide the signal inside cb is input or output ??

Thank you !

Comment: I mean if I may understand in this way that the direction of signal is just opposite between the module and interface ?

Comment: usually to define inputs and output views for an interface, `modport`s are used.  clocking block can be used to construct modports. The IO views are used to connect interface to different modules with different IO ports.

Comment: Thanks Serge. So the input/output view for each signals defined in interface class could be alternative, which depends on the modules we want to connect

Comment: yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many uses of `input/output` in SystemVerilog, which can be confusing.

For ports, they the flow of data across a boundary. For a `clocking` block, they represent whether a signal is passively being sampled, or actively driven. Depending on the situation, it is perfectly reasonable to have a port declared as an output, and the same signal declared as a clocking block input.